# FastAPI / sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite, fastapi

I need to create an endpoint that will allow me to edit customer data(company, address, city, state, country, postalcode, fax - not all .schema customers fields). The endpoint must be able to accept the json object with the following fields. I need to make sure that the client with the given id exists in the clients table. In response, the application with the code 200 is to return the customer's object. I am having this annoying error that I could not solve. Here is my function:

```
import aiosqlite
from fastapi import APIRouter, Response, status
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Customer(BaseModel):
    company: str = None
    address: str = None
    city: str = None
    state: str = None
    country: str = None
    postalcode: str = None
    fax: str = None

router = APIRouter()
@router.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    router.db_connection = await aiosqlite.connect('chinook.db')


@router.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown():
    await router.db_connection.close()

@router.put("/customers/{customer_id}")
async def update_customer(response: Response, customer_id: int, customer: Customer):
    cursor = await router.db_connection.execute(
        "SELECT CustomerId FROM customers WHERE CustomerId = ?", (customer_id, )
    )
    customer_id = await cursor.fetchone()
    if not customer_id:
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        return {"detail": {"error": "No customer found with the given customer_id!"}}
    update_date = customer.dict(exclude_unset=True)
    if update_date:
        sql = "UPDATE customers SET "
        for key, value in update_date.items():
            if key == "postalcode":
                key = "PostalCode"
            key = key.capitalize()
            sql += f"{key} = '{value}', "
        sql = sql[:-2] + f" WHERE CustomerId = {customer_id}"
        cursor = await router.db_connection.execute(sql)
        await router.db_connection.commit()
    router.db_connection.row_factory = aiosqlite.Row
    cursor = await router.db_connection.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CustomerId = ?", (customer_id, )
    )
    customer = await cursor.fetchone()
    return customer


sqlite> .schema customers
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "customers"
(
    [CustomerId] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    [Company] NVARCHAR(80),
    [Address] NVARCHAR(70),
    [City] NVARCHAR(40),
    [State] NVARCHAR(40),
    [Country] NVARCHAR(40),
    [PostalCode] NVARCHAR(10),
    [Phone] NVARCHAR(24),
    [Fax] NVARCHAR(24),
    [Email] NVARCHAR(60)  NOT NULL,
    [SupportRepId] INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY ([SupportRepId]) REFERENCES "employees" ([EmployeeId]) 
                ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
CREATE INDEX [IFK_CustomerSupportRepId] ON "customers" ([SupportRepId]);
sqlite>
```

Error look like this:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49752 - "PUT /customers/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 385, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 149, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 102, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 550, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 227, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 41, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 165, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 119, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "./routers/tracks.py", line 109, in update_customer
    cursor = await router.db_connection.execute(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiosqlite/core.py", line 209, in execute
    cursor = await self._execute(self._conn.execute, sql, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiosqlite/core.py", line 167, in _execute
    return await future
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiosqlite/core.py", line 153, in run
    result = function()
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Please, help me, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Can you connect to your database from the command line and show the output of `.schema customers`

Comment: @ Tom Carrick I added the .schema customers under the code because in the comment I had a limit on the number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in this section of code:

```py
    cursor = await router.db_connection.execute(
        "SELECT CustomerId FROM customers WHERE CustomerId = ?", (customer_id, )
    )
    customer_id = await cursor.fetchone()
    if not customer_id:
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        return {"detail": {"error": "No customer found with the given customer_id!"}}
```

`cursor.fetchone()` returns a row, not a single value, so this section changes the type of value in the variable `customer_id` from an `int` to a row.*

What you probably want to do instead is to use another variable in the check for an existing customer.  This leaves `customer_id` as it was.  I've used `customer_row` as this new variable on two of the lines below.  It doesn't need to be used anywhere else: if we get a row back from this cursor at all, the only value it contains will be the customer ID we already have:

```py
    cursor = await router.db_connection.execute(
        "SELECT CustomerId FROM customers WHERE CustomerId = ?", (customer_id, )
    )
    customer_row = await cursor.fetchone()
    if not customer_row:
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        return {"detail": {"error": "No customer found with the given customer_id!"}}
```

* I'm intentionally being a little vague on exactly what I meant by a 'row' above.  According to the [`aiosqlite` documentation](https://aiosqlite.omnilib.dev/en/latest/api.html#cursors), `cursor.fetchone()` returns an optional `sqlite3.Row`, but when I ran this code it returned a tuple.  I'm not sure it makes a huge difference either way: the point really is that neither `Row`s nor tuples are `int`s.

Comment: Thank you vary much! You helped me solve a problem! :) :) :)